# Indirekte Rede eines Satzes, welcher schon im Konjunktiv ist

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech

Als begrenztes Beispiel könnte man folgende drei Sätze in Betracht ziehen:

> 1. „Ich wäre sehr froh.“
> 2. „In dem Fall würde ich mich melden.“
> 3. „Wenn …, hätte ich keine Lust, mitzugehen.“

Die alle sind Zitate von, sagen wir mal, Bob. Nun berichtet Alice einem Dritten, und zwar schriftlich, dies, was Bob behauptet hat. Kann man da normale indirekte Rede nutzen? Was macht man, um zu betonen, dass die originale Sätze schon im Konjunktiv – sei es I oder II – waren?

Comment: Der Konjunktiv in Beispiel zwei ist überflüssig, wenn auch umgangssprachlich häufig; die Bedingung steckt ja schon in "in dem Fall".

Comment: [Canoonet](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Modi/Indirekte.html#Anchor-Indirekte-11481): "Wenn in der direkten Rede der Konjunktiv steht, muss auch in der indirekten Rede der Konjunktiv stehen."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es gibt keine weitergehende Verbform, die ausdrückt, daß man eine Aussage indirekt wiedergibt, die bereits im Konjunktiv stand. (Das ist auch nicht verwunderlich, denn wenn es eine gäbe, bräuchte diese wiederum eine weitergehende Form, falls sie selbst indirekt berichtet werden soll, und so fort ad infinitum. Die Sprache leistet hier keine unbegrenzte Ausdruckskraft, sondern nur adäquate.)

Stattdessen verwendet man einfach den originalen Konjunktiv selbst, oder wenn es darauf ankommt, die Verbform genau anzugeben, wechselt man stattdessen zur direkten Rede.